# Stack Overflow Error: Parsing with Eclipse JDT

Tags: java, parsing, stack-overflow, eclipse-jdt

I am running into a stack overflow error when running my parser on a specific system. I haven't run into the issue when parsing other, similarly sized systems, so I'm not exactly sure where the issue lies.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Detector.getNodesParents(Detector.java:201)
at Detector.getNodesParents(Detector.java:202)
at Detector.getNodesParents(Detector.java:202)
at Detector.getNodesParents(Detector.java:202)
...
```

And the most relevant part of the Detector class:

```
    private void arrangePairs() {
    System.out.println(nodes.size());
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        List<Node> parentList = getNodesParents(node, new ArrayList<Node>());
        for (Node parentNode : parentList) {
            nodePairs.add(new Pair<Node, Node>(parentNode, node));
        }
    }
    printPairs();
}

private List<Node> getNodesParents(Node node, List<Node> parentList) {
    if (node.getParent() == null) {
        return parentList;
    } else {
        parentList.add(node.getParent());
        getNodesParents(node.getParent(), parentList);
    }
    return parentList;
}
```

I'm not sure what could be causing it beyond running out of memory but at the same time, this doesn't occur for other, similarly-sized systems. I have tested that it reaches the base case (getParent == null), and it seems to stack overflow after that point.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea why that would overflow your stack on only one system (is `node.getParent()` also recursive?), but is there a reason you didn't just write `getNodesParents()` as a simple loop?

Comment: `node.getParent()` is a simple getter. A recursive solution for `getNodesParents()` seemed the most obvious to me with regards to traversing a tree but changing it to an iterative loop couldn't hurt.